# Why can't SafariDriver click on a specific element when Chrome, FF, Edge can?

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

I have a trouble when running Safari UI tests on MAC. I have an element:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ZoomBundle_people_search__searchTab-innerCt']//fieldset//span[text()='Company Information']")
```

[image]
It collapses/uncollapses a hidden block with filters.
When I perform a click() action in Chrome, FF or Edge, this action performed. But when I run the same code for Safari, I get the exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:242: ElementNotInteractableException
```

I tried to add WebDriverWait, but the result is the same. It sees the element, but can't interact with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a SafariDriver issue.
Got a suggestion to try clicking via JS:

```
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

instead

```
elem.click()
```

And it's working fine now (=

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to execute javascript, try actual simulation of pressing the keyboard Enter key as follows.

*Below sample corresponds to Python code*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Safari()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ZoomBundle_people_search__searchTab-innerCt']//fieldset//span[text()='Company Information']")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

P.S: I am still wondering, if its an issue with SafariDriver then why Apple has not looked into it yet or is it due to something else. While I continue to look out an answer you can try the above method.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe this is a bug in safaridriver, please file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ with a test case and test script. This behavior is well specified, so any divergence between implementations is probably a bug.